# JasperReports вывести в Excel числа как числа

Tags: java, jasperreports

Привет!
Есть SpringMVC проект, есть данные, которые по клику на кнопку выкачиваются в Excel файл.

Данные могут быть как число, так и текст, поэтому предыдущий программист сохранял все данные как текст. Но в итоге в Excel файле ячейки с числами имеют зеленый треугольничек с подсказкой **"Число в этой ячейке отформатировано как текст, или перед ним стоит апостроф."**

Данные для вывода заполняются так:

```
for (Integer i = startDayOfMonth; i <= endDayOfMonth; i++) {
            titleText = new JRDesignTextField();
            titleText.setX(x);
            titleText.setY(y);
            titleText.setWidth(dayColumnWidth);
            titleText.setHeight(25);
            titleText.setStyle(orangeCellStyle);
            expression = new JRDesignExpression();
            expression.setText(i.toString());
            titleText.setExpression(expression);
            band.addElement(titleText);
            x += titleText.getWidth();
            maxDayList.add(i);
        }
```

Что нужно сделать, чтобы числа выводились как числа, или чтобы не появлялся этот зеленый треуголльник?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно, делать не setText а например setFloat... или что там есть?

Answer (score 2):

Нашел решение:

В коде

```
JasperDesign jasperDesign = createListFactDesign();
    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
    JRDataSource jrDataSource = prepareDataSource();
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, jrDataSource);

    try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        switch (this.listFactReportParameters.getReportFormat()) {
            case EXCEL:
                JRXlsExporter xlsExporter = new JRXlsExporter();
                xlsExporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
                xlsExporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(baos));

                SimpleXlsReportConfiguration configuration = new SimpleXlsReportConfiguration();
                configuration.setOnePagePerSheet(false);
                configuration.setDetectCellType(true);                   
                xlsExporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
                xlsExporter.exportReport();
```

Добавил эту строку `configuration.setDetectCellType(true);`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить в jrxml файл:

```
\<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type" value="true"/>
```

и на числовые ячейки добавить паттерн:

```
\<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.pattern" value="0"/>
```